# Помогите разобраться, почему не меняется свойство CSS обратно

Tags: javascript, html, css

Если коротко, то нажав на кнопку регистрации должно открыться окошко регистрации, а кнопка авторизации должна пропасть. И с этим всё вроде бы в норме, но вот дальше... В окне регистрации справа снизу есть белая стрелочка. Она должна возвращать пользователя обратно к выбору регистрация/авторизация. Но почему то по нажатию на неё не меняется свойство `opacity` у кнопки авторизация. Звучит запутанно, понимаю. Код приложу ниже, надеюсь на помощь. (От безысходности уже и `jq` подключил, толку ноль, ну не знаю в чём проблема)
https://yadi.sk/d/LxmltL45nNVJXA

Comment: Добро пожаловать. На СО принято добавлять относящийся к вопросу отрывок кода в вопрос.

Comment: У вас вторая функция срабатывает на элементе который вложен в элемент на который срабатывает первая функция. Поэтому на втором элементе срабатывают обе функции.

Comment: код все равно лучше выложить сюда, пусть и без картинок

Comment: ссылка на яндекс диск может устареть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот переписал код, добавил код переворачивания карточки назад. Вроде работает.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $("#choose_reg .front").click(function() {
        $("#choose_reg").css({
            "transition": "500ms",
            "transform": "rotateY(180deg)",
        });
        $("#choose_auth").css({
            "transition": "500ms",
            "opacity": 0
        });
        $("#choose_reg .back").css({
            "width": "27vmax",
            "height": "40vmax",
            "margin-top": "-10vmax",
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            $("#choose_reg .back").css({ "backface-visibility": "visible",
              "display": "block" });
            $("#choose_reg .front").css({
            "display": "none"
        });
        }, 150);
    });

    $("#choose_reg .back_arrow").click(function() {
        $("#choose_reg").css({
            "transition": "500ms",
            "transform": "rotateY(0deg)",
        });
        $("#choose_reg .front").css({
            "width": "20vmax",
            "height": "20vmax",
        });
        $("#choose_auth").css({
            "transition": "500ms",
            "opacity": ""
        });
        setTimeout(() => {
            $("#choose_reg .front").css({ "display": "block" });
            $("#choose_reg .back").css({
            "display": "none"
        });
        }, 150);
    });
});
```